# Tab style missing when viewing visualforce page in lightning experience

Tags: visualforce, lightning

When creating a visualforce tab you are given the option to set a tab style which consists of an icon and a colour. This sets the icon and the background colour for components on the visualforce when viewing it in classic mode. However if you swtich to lightning experience the custom styles are not applied. Instead the icon is replaced with an empty space and all background colours revert to black.

What is the workaround to make it visible in lightning as it is visible in classic?

Comment: Hi Prateek, welccome to SFSE. Please take a moment to visit the [help] and read [ask]. As it stands, your post doesn't really contain a question, but is more of a general observation. Please [edit] it to explicitly ask a question.